# Reorienting a ladder among $\mathbb{Z}^2$ poles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Imagine an object, which I'll call a *ladder* $\cal{L}$, a "racetrack" shape
composed of a rectangle of length $L$ capped at either end by
semicircles of radius $r$; so it is $L+2r$ tip-to-tip.
View every lattice point of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a point obstacle
(a *pole*).  The ladder is forbidden to include a pole in its
interior, but $\cal{L}$ may touch poles on its boundary.
$\cal{L}$ is initially sitting in the plane in a horizontal orientation.

          
[image: Ladder Thin]

My question is:

> **Q**. 
>   Under what conditions on $L \ge 0$ and $r \le \frac{1}{2}$can $\cal{L}$ be reoriented
>   via continuous motions to a vertical orientation?

Throughout the motions, no pole may be interior to $\cal{L}$.

If $L=0$, $\cal{L}$ is a disk of radius $r$;
if $r=0$, $\cal{L}$ is a segment of length $L$.

I believe that, for $r=0$, there is no upper bound on $L$: an arbitrarily
long segment can be reoriented.
(I made this an exercise (7.3) in a
[textbook](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/DCG/).)
And certainly when $r=\frac{1}{2}$, and, say $L=1$, reorientation
is not possible.
I can see that, for $r=\frac{1}{2}$,
any $L \le \sqrt{2}-1$ can be reoriented
(because then $\cal{L}$ fits inside a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}/2$).
Almost everything else is unclear to me.

                    
[image: Ladder Fat]

An analogous question may be posed for an appropriately defined "ladder"
amidst $\mathbb{Z}^d$ obstacles.

Any insights, even for specific $(L,r)$ values, or corrections
to my beliefs above, are welcomed.  Thanks!

Comment: Each legal position of the ladder can be described by the location of its center and its angle relative to the x-axis.  Further, we do not mind translations by the integer lattice.  This means that the configuration space of ladders is some closed semi-algebraic subset of the torus T^3.  We are trying to understand the connected components.

Comment: Thank you, John, for recasting my question into such a perspicuous formulation!

Comment: Of course the problem is equivalent to rotating a segment of length L with radius r obstacle-discs around each lattice point, for me its more natural to think about it this way. A natural upper bound on L is that it must fit in any angle - is this not sufficient?

Comment: @domotorp: Yes, that viewpoint is somehow clarifying.  Thanks! 

Comment: What are the values of $L$ and $r$ for the shape in the 15-move diagram?

Comment: @Gerry: $L=3.8$, $r=0.1$. Please note I do not know if 15 is the fewest number of "moves" to reorient.

Comment: For the example (starting from position 15), I rotate the rod clockwise around a lattice point and 1) bump into a pole, so 2,3)move the lower end around that pole with  a translation and rotation, until I bump into the pole just above the first bumped pole, so I do 4,5) another translation and rotation to bring the rod to a 45 degree angle. This leads to a solution in 11 or fewer moves.  Perhaps pole-bumping is an appropriate metric related to number of moves?  Gerhard "These Poles Don't Blow Up" Paseman, 2017.03.20.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: That may not be so different from the illustration, where I counted each translation as a separate move, e.g., position $10$ to $11$. Perhaps the metric should be: Each pure rotation about a fixed point is a move, each pure translation is a move. That's what I was using.

Comment: Indeed, I am relating your metric to a pole bump metric.  My point is that to handle a length 4 rod, I need to bump 4-2=2 poles, and each pole needs two moves to move the rod end around it.  This bump metric may lead to a near optimal algorithm where the cost is number of translations and rotations. Gerhard "Excuse Me, I'm Coming Through" Paseman, 2017.03.21.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the *[EuroCG conference](http://www.diei.unipg.it/eurocg2012/)* that ended as I post this, Sándor Fekete (Braunschweig)
solved this question modulo a few details, with useful input from Günter Rote (Berlin). 
Sándor's crucial observation is that, when the ladder
is in an extreme configuration, it is touching three lattice points, which form an empty lattice
triangle, which by [Pick's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem), has area $\frac{1}{2}$, so the $L \times r$ rectangle
has area 1, and so $r \sim 1/L$.  There are many details to convert this to a formal proof,
but it seems this insight yields the right dependency between $r$ and $L$ to allow reorientability.

Curiously, at the conference a banquet bus was forced to execute a maneuver not dissimilar
from the 15-move back-&-forth path illustrated in my first figure! :-)

Comment: Actually, what you said implies $r\asymp 1/(2L)$ for large $L$ and the details are few, not many. Nice question and cool proof!